# iOS CorePlot point conversion

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot, graphing

I am experimenting with Core Plot. I am trying to add a custom "goal" label over the graph at x: 2.0, y: 50.0 - basically label over the y == 50, its in a separate view, which means I need to convert my point from Core Plot to my UIView bounds. I have not found a combination of points conversions from layer/views that works across all iPhones screen sizes. In my pictures below iPhone 6s is the closest.

iPhone 6s+: [image: iphone 6s+]

iPhone 6s: [image: iphone 6s]

iPhone 5s: [image: iphone 5s]

My view layout:
 [image: View layout]

Here is my class:

```
class BarChartViewController: UIViewController, CPTBarPlotDataSource
{
    private var barGraph : CPTXYGraph? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var graphHostingView: CPTGraphHostingView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textBoxView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

        self.title = "My results"

        let newGraph = CPTXYGraph(frame: CGRectZero)
        let theme = CPTTheme(named: kCPTPlainWhiteTheme)

        newGraph.applyTheme(theme)

        let hostingView = graphHostingView
        hostingView.hostedGraph = newGraph
        if let frameLayer = newGraph.plotAreaFrame
        {
            // Border
            frameLayer.borderLineStyle = nil
            frameLayer.cornerRadius = 0.0
            frameLayer.masksToBorder = false

            // Paddings
            newGraph.paddingLeft = 0.0
            newGraph.paddingRight = 0.0
            newGraph.paddingTop = 0.0
            newGraph.paddingBottom = 0.0

            frameLayer.paddingLeft = 70.0
            frameLayer.paddingTop = 20.0
            frameLayer.paddingRight = 20.0
            frameLayer.paddingBottom = 80.0
        }

        // Plot space
        let plotSpace = newGraph.defaultPlotSpace as? CPTXYPlotSpace
        plotSpace?.yRange = CPTPlotRange(location: 0.0, length: 100.0)
        plotSpace?.xRange = CPTPlotRange(location: 0.0, length: 4.0)

        let axisSet = newGraph.axisSet as? CPTXYAxisSet

        if let x = axisSet?.xAxis {
            x.axisLineStyle = nil
            x.majorTickLineStyle = nil
            x.minorTickLineStyle = nil
            x.majorIntervalLength = 5.0
            x.orthogonalPosition = 0.0
            x.title = "X Axis"
            x.titleLocation = 7.5
            x.titleOffset = 55.0

            // Custom labels
            x.labelRotation = CGFloat(M_PI_4)
            x.labelingPolicy = .None

            let customTickLocations = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]
            let xAxisLabels = ["Label A", "Label B", "Label C"]

            var labelLocation = 0
            var customLabels = Set<CPTAxisLabel>()
            for tickLocation in customTickLocations
            {
                let newLabel = CPTAxisLabel(text: xAxisLabels[labelLocation], textStyle: x.labelTextStyle)
                labelLocation += 1
                newLabel.tickLocation = tickLocation
                newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength
                newLabel.rotation = 0 //CGFloat(M_PI_4)
                customLabels.insert(newLabel)
            }

            x.axisLabels = customLabels
        }

        if let y = axisSet?.yAxis
        {
            y.axisLineStyle = nil
            y.majorGridLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
            var style = y.majorTickLineStyle?.mutableCopy() as? CPTMutableLineStyle
            //style!.lineColor = CPTColor(CGColor: UIColor.blackColor())   //UIColor.blackColor())
            style!.lineWidth = 10.0
            y.minorGridLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
            style = y.minorTickLineStyle?.mutableCopy() as? CPTMutableLineStyle
            //style.lineColor = UIColor.redColor()
            style!.lineWidth = 10.0
            style!.lineCap = .Round
            y.majorTickLength = 10.0
            y.majorIntervalLength = 50.0
            y.orthogonalPosition = 0.0
            y.title = "Y Axis"
            y.titleOffset = 45.0
            y.titleLocation = 150.0

            y.labelRotation = 0
            y.labelingPolicy = .None


            let customTickLocations = [50, 100]
            let yAxisLabels = ["50", "100"]

            var labelLocation = 0
            var customLabels = Set<CPTAxisLabel>()
            for tickLocation in customTickLocations
            {
                let newLabel = CPTAxisLabel(text: yAxisLabels[labelLocation], textStyle: y.labelTextStyle)
                labelLocation += 1
                newLabel.tickLocation = tickLocation
                newLabel.offset = y.labelOffset + y.majorTickLength
                newLabel.rotation = 0 //CGFloat(M_PI_4)
                customLabels.insert(newLabel)
            }

            y.axisLabels = customLabels
            var nums = Set<NSNumber>()
            nums.insert(NSNumber(double: 50.0))
            y.majorTickLocations = nums
        }

        // First bar plot
        let barPlot1 = CPTBarPlot.tubularBarPlotWithColor(CPTColor.yellowColor(), horizontalBars: false)
        barPlot1.baseValue = 0.0
        barPlot1.dataSource = self
        //barPlot1.barOffset = 0.5
        barPlot1.identifier = "Bar Plot 1"
        let textStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
        textStyle.color = CPTColor.redColor()
        textStyle.fontSize = 10.0
        barPlot1.labelTextStyle = textStyle
        newGraph.addPlot(barPlot1, toPlotSpace: plotSpace)

        self.barGraph = newGraph
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        let point: [Double] = [2.0, 50.0]
        let plotPoint = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>(point)
        var dataPoint = self.barGraph?.defaultPlotSpace?.plotAreaViewPointForDoublePrecisionPlotPoint(plotPoint, numberOfCoordinates: 2)
        //dataPoint = graphHostingView.layer.convertPoint(dataPoint!, fromLayer: self.barGraph!.plotAreaFrame!.plotArea)
        dataPoint = graphHostingView.layer.convertPoint(dataPoint!, toLayer: graphHostingView.layer.superlayer)
        //dataPoint = barGraph?.convertPoint(dataPoint!, fromLayer: graphHostingView.layer)
        dataPoint = self.textBoxView.convertPoint(dataPoint!, fromView: graphHostingView)

        print(dataPoint!)
        for item in (self.textBoxView?.constraints)!
        {
            if let id = item.identifier
            {
                if id == "goalX"
                {
                    print(item.constant)
                    item.constant = CGFloat((dataPoint?.x)!) - item.constant
                }
                else if id == "goalY"
                {
                    print(item.constant)
                    item.constant = CGFloat((dataPoint?.y)!) - item.constant
                }
            }
        }
        barGraph?.titleDisplacement = CGPoint(x: dataPoint!.x * -1, y: dataPoint!.y * -1)
        barGraph?.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = .TopLeft
        self.textBoxView?.layoutIfNeeded()
   }
}
```

Based on some other questions I have seen about CorePlot I know I need to convert it from CorePlot layer to my new view. I left some of my experiments in viewWillAppear() to see what I have tried. None of the solutions on SO seemed to work and I am new to iOS so probably missing something. Any ideas of what conversions I need to do to get my label to show up properly across all screen sizes?

Comment: I don't see any use of the graph title. Why are you updating the `titleDisplacement` and `titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor`?

Comment: Good catch, I forgot to pull that out of my example code, I had been using it in some of my experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the point conversion. This is how I would do it:

```
// Update layer layout if needed
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
graphHostingView.layer.layoutIfNeeded()

// Point in data coordinates
let point: [Double] = [2.0, 50.0]

// Data point in plot area layer coordinates
var dataPoint = self.barGraph?.defaultPlotSpace?.plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint(point)

// Convert data point to graph hosting view coordinates
dataPoint = graphHostingView.layer.convertPoint(dataPoint!, fromLayer: self.barGraph!.plotAreaFrame!.plotArea)
```

Use this to update the constraints on the text box relative to the graph hosting view.

Comment: I just tried this and i also printed out data point, on iPhone 5s, 6s, 6s+ all return same coordinates x: 325, y: 256. On 5s - goal is off screen, 6s: y is correct but x is not directly over x = 2.0 to far to the right, on 6s+: y is too small and x is too big - pushing it above the line and to far to the right. Am I incorrect in thinking that coordinates should all be different?

Comment: I forgot a step—make sure you update the layout of the layers, too. (I edited my answer.)

Comment: After your last comment I noticed that none of my views height/width was correct, which led me to layoutIfNeeded was not working in viewWillAppear. I changed my update code to viewDidLayoutSubviews and finally had my dataPoint giving me correct values. Still not entirely sure why layoutIfNeeded is not working in viewWillAppear? Thanks for getting me to answer.